# passing a nested structure to function using pointers

Tags: c, data-structures, structure

```
typedef struct
{
   int i;
}one;

typedef struct
{
   one two;
}three;

void writing_a_value(three *);

int main()
{
   three four;
   writing_a_value(&four);
   printf("%d",four.two.i);
}

void writing_a_value(three *four)
{
    four->(two->i)=1; /* problem here */
}
```

I have tried by putting braces like `(four->(two->i))=1`, but its still not working. I have to pass the pointer because I have to enter the data into the nested structure.
`error=expected ( bracket`, in the commented line.

How can i pass the structure using a pointer and enter the data in the nested structure?

Comment: I edited your code coz, its not readable. What error msg do you get ??

Comment: 0) `wriring_a_value` --> `writing_a_value` 1) `four->(two->i)=1;` --> `four->two.i=1;` 2) `printf("%d",two.i);` --> `printf("%d",four.two.i);`

Comment: You are undermining yourself with the one, two,three... naming.

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile, due to the line `printf("%d",two.i);`. `two` isn't declared in the main function anywhere

Answer (score 5):

two isn't a reference, so trying to dereference it causes errors. Instead you should only dereference four.

```
void writing_a_value(three *four)
{
        four->two.i=1; /*no problem here */
        //(*four).two.i=1 would accomplish the same thing
}
```